# (Soft) RAID 6 on Ubuntu 7.10, should I migrate to 8.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

My System is a Ubuntu 7.10. I have a (soft) RAID 6 with 5 disks (Samsung 500GB SATA disks), formatted with jfs. Should I upgrade to 8.10 or isn't it worth the hassle? What are the chances that something could happen to the RAID configuration? I don't want to be in the position to rebuild the RAID from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been running soft raid5 on Ubuntu since 6.10, and always upgraded without problems.

Note that in Jaunty (9.04), which is not LTS, there's a bug where degraded arrays don't start automatically.

Comment: I did the upgrade and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 7):

First off, 7.10 and 8.10 are not LTS (long term support) release. The only LTS releases so far are 6.06 and 8.04.

Secondly, 7.10 is [no longer supported](http://www.ubuntu.com/news/ubuntu-7.10-eol) - that means that you will no longer receive security updates (or any other updates). So you should definitely upgrade to the 8.04 LTS release (known as the Hardy Heron).

To do so (assuming you don't have a desktop environment installed) then install update-manager-core if it is not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Launch the upgrade tool

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Follow the on-screen instructions. (Instructions from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardyUpgrades) )

Comment: Given the age of 7.10, you might need to update your sources.list in order to use apt (if you haven't already).

Instead of 'archive.ubuntu.com' or 'security.ubuntu.com' you should have something like this:

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ feisty universe main restricted multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ feisty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ feisty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ feisty-security universe main restricted multiverse